# Explanation required for address of union members

Tags: c++

I have written the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

union Packed
{
   char     i;
   short    j;
   int      k;
   long     l;
   float    f;
   double   d;
};

int main()
{
  cout<<"sizeof(Packed) = "<< sizeof(Packed)<<endl;
  Packed x;
  cout<<"Address j ="<<&(x.j)<<endl;
  cout<<"Address i ="<<&(x.i)<<endl;
  cout<<"Address k ="<<&(x.k)<<endl;
  cout<<"Address l ="<<&(x.l)<<endl;
  cout<<"Address f ="<<&(x.f)<<endl;
  cout<<"Address d ="<<&(x.d)<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

## Output:

```
sizeof(Packed) = 8

Address j =0x7fff587a71a0
Address i =

Address k =0x7fff587a71a0
Address l =0x7fff587a71a0
Address f =0x7fff587a71a0
Address d =0x7fff587a71a0
```

When I altered the code as follows:

```
  cout<<"Address j ="<<(long)&(x.j)<<endl;
  cout<<"Address i ="<<(long)&(x.i)<<endl;
  cout<<"Address k ="<<(long)&(x.k)<<endl;
  cout<<"Address l ="<<(long)&(x.l)<<endl;
  cout<<"Address f ="<<(long)&(x.f)<<endl;
  cout<<"Address d ="<<(long)&(x.d)<<endl;
```

I get the output:

```
Address j =140736718889408
Address i =140736718889408
Address k =140736718889408
Address l =140736718889408
Address f =140736718889408
Address d =140736718889408
```

I am little bit confused that why I am not getting a proper address in case of character variable in a union when I am just printing base address for all variables in a union which is supposed to be same as confirmed when "long" typecasted in the second part of the code.

Please provide an explanation for the confusion.The outputs are listed as obtained on a Fedora FC17 Linux machine.

Comment: If you think it is related to unions, why not try to print the address of variables that are *not* in a union?

Comment: When you pass a `char *`, the stream thinks you want to print a C-style string rather than the pointer's value itself.

Answer (score 5):

There's an overload for char const* variable in ostreams. Cast all pointer to void const* to get proper results.

Oh, and before I forget: Use static_cast() and don't ever use C-style casts unless you really know that you have to!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is that C++ ostreams overload `operator <<` for `char *` and takes them as  a pointer to the C-style (NULL terminated) string and print it. Because `Packed x` is the union type object put on stack it has automatic storage duration and is not initialized to 0 (it would be the case if x had static or thread storage duration). So the value of `x.i` is undefined and this is why you have experienced the *print-nothing* behavior

```
Packed x;
cout<<"Address i ="<<&(x.i)<<endl; // nothing gets printed
```

This is undefined behavior.

You should cast the expression to a `void const*` pointer to print the address itself

```
Packed x;
cout<<"Address i ="<< static_cast< void const*> ( &x.i) << endl;
```

Comment: As the specializatuin dereferences, it is UB.

Comment: @Yakk do you mean **it is** UB? This is an attempt to print a char right? One character. It is some character, so does it matter what it is exactly?

Comment: if you pass an uninitialized `char const*` or `char*` to `std::ostream::operator<<` it dereferences it (UB right off the bat possibly, as I am unsure if `char` trap values are illegal), then increments it until it finds a `'\0'` terminator (UB as soon as it increments twice, as the only legal addresses are data and one-offset-past-end of data, or once it increments once and reads).

Comment: @Yakk but passed character has some character value, right? It is indeterminate but it is some character.

Comment: unsure: I think a 9-bit computer, where the extra bit is never used by any initialized data, and it acts as a trap bit whereby reading from data with it set causes program termination, would be legal under the C++ standard, but I am uncertain: the rules for `char` are unlike the rules for other types sometimes.  I am, as I have said already, uncertain in this case.  This is, however, unimportant to the code you quoted as that code is UB regardless.